The role of probability in the many-worlds interpretation
A quantum system can transition to one of two states, with probabilities 30% and 70%. The many worlds interpretation says that the universe splits into two, one for each state. If so, what do the 30% and 70% mean?

Related, possible duplicate: How does many worlds interpretation work for non-50/50 probabilities?

Does this answer your question? How does many worlds interpretation work for non-50/50 probabilities?

It is probably wrong .

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808788/how-would-one-calculate-the-actual-probability-of-a-macro-event-given-what-we-kn/808859#808859
